# Compare rows values of same table in mysql with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like this:

```
header_id | class | start_date | end_date
-------------------------------------------
1         | c1    | 20-08-2019 | 22-08-2019
1         | c1    | 22-08-2019 | 24-08-2019
1         | c2    | 24-08-2019 | 27-08-2019
2         | c3    | 21-08-2019 | 22-08-2019
2         | c2    | 22-08-2019 | 25-08-2019
2         | c3    | 25-08-2019 | 26-08-2019
```

I want to get the following results:

```
header_id | class | start_date | end_date
-------------------------------------------
1         | c1    | 20-08-2019 | 24-08-2019
1         | c2    | 24-08-2019 | 27-08-2019
2         | c3    | 21-08-2019 | 22-08-2019
2         | c2    | 22-08-2019 | 25-08-2019
2         | c3    | 25-08-2019 | 26-08-2019
```

if header_id is same, class is same, and the end date of the previous data is same as the start date of the data after that, it will take the minimum date from the start date and the maximum date on the end date. however, if the previous data's end date is different from the start date on the data after that, then the data will be displayed normally.

Is there a way to get that result ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [group by](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx)
Example [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48203/how-to-get-max-and-min-in-group-by-query)

```
SELECT header_id, class, MIN(start_date), MAX(end_date) FROM your-table
GROUP BY header_id, class
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could work, by using aggregate function `min` and `max`:

```
SELECT header_id, class, min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
FROM table_name
Group by header_id, class
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky this one but you can `LEFT JOIN` the table itself then use a combination of `LEAST`, `GREATEST` and `MIN MAX` function like this:

```
SELECT header_id,class,MIN(st_date),MAX(en_date) FROM
   (SELECT a.header_id,a.class,
           LEAST(IFNULL(a.start_date,b.start_date),IFNULL(b.start_date,a.start_date)) AS st_date,
           GREATEST(IFNULL(a.end_date,b.end_date),IFNULL(b.end_date,a.end_date)) AS en_date
    FROM   testing a 
    LEFT JOIN testing b ON a.header_id=b.header_id 
    AND a.class=b.class 
    AND a.start_date=b.end_date) A
GROUP BY header_id,class,st_date
ORDER BY header_id,class,st_date;
```

Refer fiddle here : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m5HQ5rrVHu4FQNBEeqc7j9/0